# Python - Create new column (summation) in date range - Rolling Sum?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, sum, time-series

I am trying to create a new column in my dataframe:

Let X be a variable number of days.

|  | Date | Units Sold | Total Units sold in the last X days |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2019-01-01 19:00:00 | 5 |  |
| 1 | 2019-01-01 15:00:00 | 4 |  |
| 2 | 2019-01-05 11:00:00 | 1 |  |
| 3 | 2019-01-12 12:00:00 | 3 |  |
| 4 | 2019-01-15 15:00:00 | 2 |  |
| 5 | 2019-02-04 18:00:00 | 7 |  |

For each row, I need to sum up units sold + all the units sold in the last 10 days (letting x = 10 days)

Desired Result:

|  | Date | Units Sold | Total Units sold in the last X days |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2019-01-01 19:00:00 | 5 | 5 |
| 1 | 2019-01-01 15:00:00 | 4 | 9 |
| 2 | 2019-01-05 11:00:00 | 1 | 10 |
| 3 | 2019-01-12 12:00:00 | 3 | 4 |
| 4 | 2019-01-15 15:00:00 | 2 | 6 |
| 5 | 2019-02-04 18:00:00 | 7 | 7 |

I have used the `.rolling(window=)` method before using periods and I think the following can help

`df = df.rolling(window='10D', on='date').sum()`  but I can't get the syntax right!!

I have tried
`df["Total Units sold in the last 10 days"] = df.rolling(on="date", window="10D", closed="both").sum()["Units Sold"]` but get the error

**"ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 2, placement implies 1"** and **"ValueError: Shape of passed values is (500, 2), indices imply (500, 1)"**

Please please help!

Comment: Do you care about the time or just the date?

Comment: I was thinking I had to keep the time because there are entries that are on the same day but different time... but I will end up doing the monthly rolling sum.

Comment: Monthly rolling sum? As in group each month together and get the rolling sum for each month? Or group by the last n number of days. Fore example should Jan. 1 and Dec. 31 ever be in the same group? How do you handle months with 28, 29, 30 or 31 days?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your sample data, you need to specify **on** parameter.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': [pd.Timestamp('2019-01-01 15:00:00'),
  pd.Timestamp('2019-01-01 19:00:00'),
  pd.Timestamp('2019-01-05 11:00:00'),
  pd.Timestamp('2019-01-12 12:00:00'),
  pd.Timestamp('2019-01-15 15:00:00'),
  pd.Timestamp('2019-02-04 18:00:00')],
 'Units Sold': [4, 5, 1, 3, 2, 7],
 'Total Units sold in the last X days': [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan]})
df = df.sort_values("Date")
df["Total Units sold in the last X days"] = df.rolling("10D", on="Date").sum()["Units Sold"]
df
```

|  | Date | Units Sold | Total Units sold in the last X days |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2019-01-01 15:00:00 | 4 | 4 |
| 1 | 2019-01-01 19:00:00 | 5 | 9 |
| 2 | 2019-01-05 11:00:00 | 1 | 10 |
| 3 | 2019-01-12 12:00:00 | 3 | 4 |
| 4 | 2019-01-15 15:00:00 | 2 | 5 |
| 5 | 2019-02-04 18:00:00 | 7 | 7 |

Comment: Thank you I did BUT I get the error "ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 2, placement implies 1" and "ValueError: Shape of passed values is (500, 2), indices imply (500, 1)". what does that mean?

Comment: do you get that with my code and DF as well?  if so versions... python 3.9.4, pandas 1.2.5

Comment: THANK YOU. The problem was when I reset the index. So I sorted the data and then did df.reset_index and somehow that changed the shape of the dataframe. Thank you again :)